# How to collapse and uncollapse (toggle) the body field in teaser display?

Tags: entities

I have a list of **teaser** nodes. The **body** field is shown as trimmed with a **read more** link which leads to another page to view the full display of the node. So far so good.

I need to change this to: when the **read more** button is clicked all the content of the body field is **uncollapsed** (slidedown) and a **less** button is shown. Then f I click it the body field is **collapsed** again (slideup)

I think there must be a module to do this, since is a very popular practice.

Comment: Dont you think that using jQuery to show/hide content is good enough for this? I mean you are already loading the teaser why not load the whole body and once the read more button is clicked the rest of the body will be shown?

Comment: I know I can do it programmatically but I think a formatter would be very handy for others fields/situations. btw: I found this one: http://drupal.org/project/jquery_expander and this http://drupal.org/project/expanding_formatter

Comment: That works, But I think thats a little over kill for a small functionality dont you think?

Comment: The [jQuery expander](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_expander) module works fine to address this question. Here is a quote from its project page: > Field formatter to expand and collapse text of a field.

Comment: I've tried both [jQuery expander](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_expander) and [Expanding Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/expanding_formatter). I've chosen the former, jQuery expander, because it has the more/less functionality while the latter seems only to offer expanding functionality (maybe smoother but not sufficient for my case).

Comment: What about using [views accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) - are you using views for your teaser list? Here is a quote from the module's project page: > Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.
It will take the results and display them as a JQuery [accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)), using the first field as the header for the accordion rows.

Comment: On a second thought, I think the two projects have different and complementary functionalities (I wish they could merge). 
In fact [Expanding formatter](https://drupal.org/project/expanding_formatter) lack the collapse functionality, but it can show human edited summary if present; on the other hand [jQuery expander](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_expander) has the collapse functionality, but only control trim version of the text.

Comment: The Jquery Expander module has a broken link to its library. I was able to use the [Expanding Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/expanding_formatter) to fit a use-case similar to yours. In order to get it to work, you must manage the display settings of the content type you want this to work on. I chose Articles. The display to update is "Teasers". If you do not see a tab for teasers, make sure you're on teh default tab, and near the bottom click on custom tabs, and then select "Teasers". Now you'll see the Teaser tab next to default. I changed the Body display from "default" to "trimme

Comment: Just so if anyone looking for D8 version for Jquery expander here is the link https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_expander/issues/2686007. It works perfectly fine with Drupal 8.6.10.