# Collapsible text in Drupal 7 - tried several guides, need for dummies version

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

Running Drupal 7.39 and CorporateClean theme and Ctools module installed.

I want to be able to have sections of collapsable text.

I read the following (and some others, which I can't link due to restrictions): 
 - [How to collapse and uncollapse (toggle) the body field in teaser display?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65368/how-to-collapse-and-uncollapse-toggle-the-body-field-in-teaser-display)
 - http://timonweb.com/posts/painless-collapsible-divs-in-drupal/

The things I tried do NOT work.

I would appreciate a for dummies version including

- which sub-module of CTools I need to enable
- if I need to add code, where exactly it needs to go? I know I can't
  just paste it willy-nilly.

The old page worked with the following code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files/deflist.css" /> 

<dl class="committee">
<dt><a class='toggle'><Title</dt>
<dd>
<p>content<p>
<p class='close'>Close</p></dd>
```

Even if I move the deflist.js and deflist.css into the src path, the old code doesn't work.

For reference, this is the content of deflist.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('dl.committee> dd').hide();
  $('dl.committee> dt> a.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('fast');
  });
  $('dl.committee> dd> p.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

and this deflist.css

```
dd img {float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0;}
dl.committee dd {height:250px;}
dd p.close {text-align:right; margin-right:20px; font-size:0.85em; cursor:pointer;}
dl {padding:5px 0 0 0; border-bottom:1px solid #E1E1E1;}
dt {padding:0 0 5px 0; border-top:1px solid #E1E1E1;}
dt a {background: url('/sites/all/themes/acquia_marina/images/green-bullet.png') no-repeat left 0.20em;   
  padding-left: 1.20em; 
  cursor:pointer;}
```

I'm wondering if the reason would be that the background url above is from the old theme...

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: jQuery is in no-conflict mode so that could be the first thing to look at (wrap the code in deflist.js in `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`). Do you have errors in the JS console?

Comment: You see, when I meant "for dummies" was that I can't make sense of what you're asking! (Sorry!)